# issue that state is undefined in vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

[image]

[image]

the error is TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Comment: Show the code is causing this error

Comment: I posted the function up

Comment: Now please add `this.state` definition. And one more thing: don't modify a state directly. Only by using actions and mutations

Comment: [_DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello inside actions and mutations you need to pass the state to function

First arg u get state action mutations, second one u pass a payload
So your code should look like this

```
gatherine({ state}, payload)
```

Then you don't need to use this.state and directly use state